# Not Conforming to the Delegate in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a protocol DataProviderDelegate which is defined below:

```
protocol DataProviderDelegate : class {

    typealias Object

}
```

Now, I have a class which inherits this protocol as shown below:

```
extension ShoppingListTableViewController : DataProviderDelegate {
}
```

The error is that the ShoppingListTableViewController does not conform to the DataProviderDelegate protocol. I can see that I have not implemented the Object typealias but if it is required how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try add this line in ShoppingListTableViewController hope this can help you :)

```
typealias Object = AnyObject
```

Comment: Thanks could you please recommend as correct answer :)